# How do I make my random index progress through a whole array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing, arc4random

Currently my code spits out a random index from an array of keys and values. However the index stays the same and displays the same keys and values but what I want it to do is display one random index the iterate through the arrays and display another random index that is not equal to the previous random index. How could I implement this?

Here is my code (swift for iOS):

```
class QuestionDetails {
     let QADictionary = ["Who is Thor's brother?" : ["Atum", "Loki", "Red Norvell", "Kevin Masterson"], "What is the name of Thor's hammer?" : ["Mjolinr", "Uru", "Stormbreaker", "Thundara"], "Who is the father of Thor?" : ["Odin", "Sif", "Heimdall", "Balder"]]  
}

//get question list
func questionWithAnswers() {
     let listQuestions = QuestionDetails()

     //array of keys/questions
     var questionList = Array(listQuestions.QADictionary.keys)

     //random question index
     var rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questionList.count)))
     var randAnswers = rand

     //array of values/answers
     var answerList = Array(listQuestions.QADictionary.values)

     //button answer choices
     var choices = answerList[randAnswers]

     //fetch questions from list
     let question = questionList[rand]

     //function for new question and button titles
     questionLabel.text = question
     rightAnswerBox = arc4random_uniform(4)+1

     //create button
     var button:UIButton = UIButton()
     var x = 1

     for index in 1...4 {
         button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton
         if (index == Int(rightAnswerBox)) {
             button.setTitle(choices[0], for: .normal)
         } else {
             button.setTitle(choices[x], for: .normal)
             x += 1
         }
         randomImage()
     }
}
```

Comment: Use this https://github.com/nvzqz/RandomKit maybe can help you

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to solve this, and randomly display elements from a whole array without repeats, is to create another array of indexes, one index for each item in your main array, and randomly shuffle it.  Then just step through that shuffled array of indexes, and use the now-randomized index order to display items from your main array.